# Return rows in random order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to write SQL query that returns table rows in random order every time the query run?

Comment: I vote to reopen; the "duplicate" question is not specific to MS-SQL server, so you have to wade through a ton of info that is not relevant if you are looking for MS-SQL

Comment: @MarkSowul it's not specific to MS-SQL, it's applicable to *all* SQL types, which is what canonical duplicates are for. Further, "wade through a ton of info" is nonsense; the MS SQL solution is pinned to the top of the page in the *accepted answer* (which has the highest score by a factor of 20, if you care to sort answers that way).

Comment: It's not "nonsense" (I thought we're supposed to be friendly here?).  The 'accepted answer' is not one size fits all (look at the upvoted comments), and trying to find other alternatives involves lots of other answers that are not relevant if you are looking for a specific DBMS, especially since most of the answers don't even mention what DBMS they are for.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: For MySQL use `ORDER BY uuid()`. (...for those arriving on this page via a generic search, like me!)

Comment: This works, but is insanely slow on the table I'm selecting from (14M+ rows). Is that to be expected? AFAIK, the table is properly indexed.

Comment: @John - You are selecting 14 million records and generating and ordering by a uniqueidentifier.  Perhaps yuo're only after a single random row?  In this case, do SELECT TOP 1 FROM table ORDER BY NEWID()

Comment: @DaveBarker That's exactly what I'm after. It's for system integration testing. I'm selecting a random invoice id from our invoices table. I'm doing exactly as you suggested, but it is still ridiculously slow. The time is measured in minutes.

Comment: @John - Is your InvoiceId an integer and is it an identity column in incrementing order?

Comment: @DaveBarker It is an integer. It is not an identity. It is the primary key (clustered, unique, primary key).

Comment: @John Kraft - If the numbers are incrementing and there aren't too many gaps in the number order then you could use the RAND function. Declare InvoiceId INT SELECT InvoiceId = RAND() * (SELECT MAX(InvoiceId) - MIN(InvoiceId) FROM table) PRINT InvoiceId SELECT * FROM table Where InvoiceId = InvoiceId
Note: The InvoiceId should have the at sign but SO is unhappy with that

Comment: @DaveBarker Seems to work exactly as I wanted, and it's extremely fast. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do I do if I want to perform further manipulations of this data? i.e. if I'm randomizing it and then grabbing the top 10%, how do I then sort that 10%? order by is, sadly, invalid in subqueries in TSQL.

Comment: That does not work in MySQL.

Comment: For Postgres it's `ORDER BY random()`.

Comment: Might need a different solution within a stored proc or function. 
`"Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'newid' within a function."`

Answer (score 29):

This is the simplest solution:

```
SELECT quote FROM quotes ORDER BY RAND()
```

Although it is not the most efficient. [This one](http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/) is a better solution.

Comment: Pretty sure that doesn't work. The RAND() in the ORDER BY clause is only calculated once, so you end up with a natural order. To test it, try ORDER BY RAND(), 1 and you'll get a list of your quotes orderd by the first column (at least in SQL Server 2005).

Comment: Hm, I'm pretty sure this has worked for me in the past, perhaps it depends on the product you use.

Comment: It's don't seems that it works on MS SQL.

Comment: This does not work and I guess you did not try this either. RAND() is fixed for the duration of the SELECT on MS SQL Server. You have to use NEWID()

Comment: ...and the tag was "tsql": which implies MS SQL Server usually.

Comment: But yes, it would work on MySQL :)

Comment: the uuid() and newid() technique does not work for me on mysql, this answer did.

Comment: This solution can't work on SQL Server. If you want this to work, you can create an `OUTER APPLY` with an subquery which generates the `RAND`. But the Solution with `NEWID()` is much better.

Comment: I've tested it personally. This works only in MySQL, so it is a more valid solution than `NEWID()` which does not work in MySQL, that is in the case of MySQL.

Comment: `RAND`  works fine with phpmyadmin......

Answer (score 12):

The usual method is to use the NEWID() function, which generates a unique GUID. So,

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Foo ORDER BY NEWID();
```

Comment: The obvious choice, the RAND() function doesn't work directly, but here's a workaround: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2004/11/22/2927.aspx

Comment: +1 it works, but Dave Barker was faster :)

Answer (score -1):

To be efficient, and random, it might be best to have two different queries.

Something like...

SELECT table_id FROM table

Then, in your chosen language, pick a random id, then pull that row's data.

SELECT * FROM table WHERE table_id = $rand_id

But that's not really a good idea if you're expecting to have lots of rows in the table.  It would be better if you put some kind of limit on what you randomly select from.  For publications, maybe randomly pick from only items posted within the last year.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example ([source](http://www.rankspike.com/seo-helpful-tips/how-to-randomize-in-sql/)):

```
SET @randomId = Cast(((@maxValue + 1) - @minValue) * Rand() + @minValue AS tinyint);
```

Answer (score -3):

***SQL Server / MS Access Syntax:***

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table_name ORDER BY RAND()
```

***MySQL Syntax:***

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: The question was tagged SQL Server.  The RAND() doesn't work and the LIMIT isn't recognized, nor does the question ask to limit the results to one record.