# Excel VBA: SQL Query to Return n Rows in Random Order

Tags: excel, vba, random

I am doing a query against a range in Excel to pull records. I need 5 records selected in random from a pool of 15. I did some research and could find a syntax for random ordering in MySQL and T-SQL. Here is a question from SO that summarizes these examples: [Return rows in random order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117761/sql-query-to-return-rows-in-random-order)

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY NEWID()` - from T-SQL

Is there a similar `NEWID()` or `UUID()` syntax available in Excel VBA, and if not, what is an elegant solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this: http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/newsgroups/rand_selection/index.html#rand_and_rank