# How to prevent duplicated records when applying ORDER BY NEWID() to fetch them randomly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-order-by, newid

I tried using the solution provided in [Return rows in random order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117761/sql-query-to-return-rows-in-random-order) to fetch random records in my query. But I have to add `NEWID()` to the list of columns I want to fetch or otherwise I will not be able to add `ORDER BY NEWID()` . Unfortunately it makes my resultset to contain duplicate records.

For more clarification, this query makes my results to have duplicates due to existence of NEWID() among requested columns:

```
SELECT distinct top 4 
              Books.BookID,
              Books.Authors,                  
              Books.ShortTitle,               
              NEWID()                 
  FROM Books 
  inner join Publishers on Books.PublisherID = Publishers.PublisherID

  ORDER BY NEWID()
```

How can I overcome this issue of not fetching unique records (Here BookID is PK)?

Comment: If `BookID` is a primary key, how do you get any duplicate values at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely *don't* want to add `newid()` to each row.  That will undo the `distinct`.  Instead, use `group by` with `order by`newid()`:

```
  SELECT top 4 b.BookID, b.Authors, b.ShortTitle              
  FROM Books b inner join
       Publishers p
       on b.PublisherID = p.PublisherID
  GROUP BY b.BookId, b.Authors, B.ShortTitle
  ORDER BY NEWID();
```

It will work fine.  You can order by values that are not in the `select` list.

Comment: No. It doesn't work. Error: ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: @Farshid . . . It looked funny after I wrote it.  The answer is fixed with `group by`.

Comment: You removed DISTINCT . Won't it affect uniqueness of records?

Comment: @Farshid . . . No.  The `group by` removes duplicate values.

Comment: Thanks Gordon and Zane

Answer (score 3):

Or if you still want to use NEWID, just make a distinct list before assigning the new id:

```
SELECT a.BookID, a.Authors, a.ShortTitle FROM
(SELECT distinct top 4 
          Books.BookID AS BookID,
          Books.Authors AS Authors,                  
          Books.ShortTitle AS ShortTitle,                              
FROM Books 
inner join Publishers on Books.PublisherID = Publishers.PublisherID) a
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: No I don't want to mention NEWID() in my columns. It makes results to have douplicates,

Comment: Ok if you remove the NEWID() from the top row in the select statement, it will still assign each row a NEWID and return random unique values.

Comment: I made the adjustment to the code above - hope that helps