# How to randomize questions in a quiz application without repetition and without exiting on the first wrong answer?

Tags: android

This is my first time to post anything here and i am not so good with the formatting yet and this post isnt perfect either. I just really need help. Im a noob.

The getannswer function is where the events are controlled depending on the users input.

```
public void getAnswer(String AnswerString) {
    if (this.ans.equals(AnswerString)) {

        // if conditions matches increase the int (score) by 1
        // and set the text of the score view
        this.score++;
        this.scored.setText("" + this.score);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CORRECT!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        db.getQuestion();
    } else {

        // if the answer is wrong start activity and finish the test

        Intent intent = new Intent(Testactivity.this, result.class);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WRONG, SORRY!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        db.getScore(test_entry.username, this.score);

        // passing the int value
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("score", score); // Your score
        intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

}
```

getquestion is where I tried to implement a way to get questions from the database. My problem here is that I cant get it to skip questions it has already taken. As you can see, I tried to use images in some questions but that didnt work out so well and its not the point of the question.

```
public void getQuestion() {
    Random r = new Random();
    int n = r.nextInt(20);
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ctr++;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST + " WHERE `qid` = " + n + ";", null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        if(cursor.getInt(6) == 1) {
            ta.txtQuestion.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ta.txtQuestion.setText(cursor.getString(1).toString());
            /*Log.e("IMAGE", "I WAS HERE");
            ta.img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            int imageResource = draw.getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/"+cursor.getString(1), null, PACKAGE);
            Drawable res = draw.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
            ta.img.setImageDrawable(res);
            //ta.img.setImageResource(imageResource);*/
        } else {
            ta.txtQuestion.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ta.txtQuestion.setText(cursor.getString(1).toString());
        }
        ta.button1.setText(cursor.getString(3).toString());
        ta.button2.setText(cursor.getString(4).toString());
        ta.button3.setText(cursor.getString(5).toString());
        ta.ans = cursor.getString(2).toString();
        Log.e("Current Question ID", Integer.toString(n));
        Testactivity.txtCounter.setText(Integer.toString(ctr));
    }
```

If I have left out any relevant piece of code or description.. Please let me know so I could update this post.

```
public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
    List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
    dbase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
           // Question quest = new Question();
            //quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
            Question quest = new Question();
            quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
            quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
            quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(5));
            quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(2));
            quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(3));
            quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(4));

            quesList.add(quest);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    // return quest list
    return quesList;
}
```

the one above is the newer function that gets the questions from the database. however. I am not able to use the NEWID() function which was supposed to return rows with randomly generated IDs. Or maybe my understanding is just wrong in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should retrieve all of the questions, store them in whatever `Collection` you want, and then just go to the next question in `getQuestion`.

When you retrieve your questions from the database you can tell SQL to return in a [random order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1117774/2168085).

If that SO answer for whatever reason has been changed here is the relevant part of the answer:

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY RANDOM()
```

So you'd be removing you `WHERE` clause from your query because you now want to retrieve all questions, however the `ORDER BY NEWID()` will return them in random order.

Comment: This may sound like a dumb question.. What is the collection for?

Comment: Collections are used to store one or more items. I have a sneaking suspicion that I may be helping you with an assignment so I would encourage you to search for "Collection JavaDoc" and that will hopefully clear things up for you.

Comment: So apparently.. I cant just call NEWID(). I thought that it was function. I also made what I hope to be a new function for getting questions. How do I use NEWID?

Comment: My apologies you want `ORDER BY RANDOM()` instead, `NEWID()` exists in MySQL but not SQLite.